# Redirecting subprocess.call output not working

Tags: python, shell, unix, redirect, grep

I'm attempting to write a python script that acts as a simple UNIX bash command shell. I need to block all output from my script and redirect it to one of two files (errors or output). Unfortunately, when running my bash command on a directory I get the output "grep: test_dir: Is a directory". This is after redirecting my sys.stdout to a temporary file. My theory is that grep itself is resetting the output and printing this error as opposed to simply returning the output. Is there a way where I can redirect any and all output to a file? Or am I just misunderstanding how to redirect in python?

Here is my current code.

```
try:
    temp_out = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open('./temp.txt', 'w+')
    output = subprocess.call(['grep', search[0], search[1]])
    sys.stdout = temp_out
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    print output
    err_output = err.returncode
    print "In error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.stderr),

> stdout is used for the output of print() and expression statements and for the prompts of input();

My guess is it doesn't work for sub process.

One way to do this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', search[0], search[1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
sys.stdout.write(out) # you have to decode byte to str if it's Python3
sys.stderr.write(err)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! It separates both the return value and possible errors to different variables that I can manipulate.

Comment: @JacobChesley Actually if you only want to redirect the output and error of subprocess into files, 9000's solution is better. If you want to redirect everything including `print(...)` in your program, mine is better.

Comment: In this case I wanted to redirect all output of the subprocess including the print. This was so I can manipulate all output to the format that I need. In this case your solution was what I was looking for, though 9000's is a good idea to keep under the hood for future endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

Do not replace `sys.stdout`; open a normal file and pass it as the `stdout` parameter.

```
with open('destination.txt', 'w') as redirected_output:
  p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=redirected_output)
  p.communicate()
```

Just worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I needed to redirect any output that the subprocess itself sends to stdout. This only redirects the return value which my program already did. The ls command doesnt have this error problem, or at least with that particular call.